# Where to get the Active Accessibility 2.0 SDK

Tags: windows

I'm looking for the Active Accessibility 2.0 SDK but the link on Microsoft Download Center is no longer valid. Do you guys know another place where I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess the MSAA SDK is now part of the [Windows Automation API SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/winuiautomation/windows-automation-api-sdk-tools), which in its turn is included in the [Windows SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).